# Unable to fill vector drawable with color

Tags: android-studio, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to split an XML with a drawable of an insole in 3 regions which I want to fill with a color. I have tried editing the file but I wasn't able to fill in the region with a color.

I have the following XML file which works:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="4.44444dp"
android:height="12.4444dp"
android:viewportWidth="400"
android:viewportHeight="1120">
<path
  android:pathData="M152,28.21C171.99,31.28 184.34,33.17 203,42.26 241.18,60.87 267.02,93.2 289.69,128 289.69,128 301.55,146 301.55,146 301.55,146 311.3,164 311.3,164 324.56,188.15 336.37,212.4 346.6,238 362.69,278.26 373.25,320.32 380.41,363 380.41,363 387.09,424 387.09,424 387.09,424 388,436 388,436 388,436 388,479 388,479 388,479 387.09,491 387.09,491 385.01,521.27 379.69,551 375.27,581 370.37,614.29 367.2,647.49 364.91,681 364.91,681 364,694 364,694 364,694 363.04,705 363.04,705 363.04,705 363.04,717 363.04,717 363.04,717 362,730 362,730 362,730 362,745 362,745 362,745 361,760 361,760 361,760 361,869 361,869 361,869 362,886 362,886 362,886 363,939 363,939 363,939 362.04,952 362.04,952 359.93,1000.5 344.79,1048.52 300,1074.13 292.36,1078.49 283.46,1082.44 275,1084.86 266.13,1087.4 254.2,1089.89 245,1090 230.5,1090.17 218.05,1089.47 204,1085.28 194.01,1082.3 186.85,1079.09 178,1073.58 143.6,1052.16 129.3,1017.62 123.73,979 123.73,979 121,953 121,953 121,953 120,918 120,918 120,918 121,903 121,903 121,903 121,888 121,888 121,888 122,868 122,868 122,868 123,846 123,846 123,846 124.04,831 124.04,831 124.04,831 124.04,816 124.04,816 124.04,816 125,804 125,804 125,804 125,781 125,781 125,781 126,765 126,765 126,765 126,744 126,744 126,744 125,727 125,727 124.93,680.6 118.93,630.95 107.12,586 90.97,524.56 64.84,480.13 42.2,423 27.1,384.88 17.91,348.79 13.83,308 13.83,308 12,287 12,287 12,287 12,239 12,239 12,239 12.91,227 12.91,227 12.91,227 14.83,200 14.83,200 20.59,142.4 33.12,73.84 88,42.43 96.33,37.66 103.76,34.68 113,32.15 121.71,29.77 133.99,28.01 143,28.21 143,28.21 152,28.21 
  152,28.21ZM340.28,228M380.13,375"
  android:strokeWidth="1"
  android:strokeColor="#000000"/> </vector>
```

This XML file gives the following output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhhbp.jpg

I have tried to convert this to a JPG file to edit it as editing the svg just didn't work out for me. After that I made 1 region which I wanted to use, which is the following output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3F4Y.jpg

XML code which doesn't work as intended:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="1280dp"
android:height="3584dp"
android:viewportWidth="1280"
android:viewportHeight="3584">
<path
  android:pathData="M429,89.7C355.1,96.7 297.6,118.4 241.4,160.6C223.8,173.8 199.7,196.8 185,214.5C180.9,
  219.4 177.3,223.7 177,224C174.7,226.3 162.7,242.9 155.8,253.5C103.6,332.9 71,436 52.5,580.5C49.4,604.8 46,
  638.1 44.5,659C43.7,670.8 41.6,698.9 40,721.3C37,761.6 37,763.2 37,841.5C37,917.9 37.1,922.1 39.5,
  949.7C44.9,1011.7 49.2,1045.3 58.4,1097C59.7,1104.4 61.8,1114.5 68.4,1146C72.1,1163.8 83.6,1207.3 91.2,
  1232.5C102.5,1270.2 125,1334.2 136.5,1361.5C138.3,1365.9 143.1,1377.4 147.1,1387C158.6,1414.9 161.4,
  1421.5 168.8,1438.5C177.4,1458.2 183.5,1472 185.9,1477.4C187,1479.7 189.7,1485.8 192,1491C194.3,
  1496.2 198.4,1505.2 201,1511C203.7,1516.8 208.7,1528 212.3,1536C215.8,1544 221.9,1557.5 225.7,1566C229.6,
  1574.5 236,1588.9 240,1598C243.9,1607.1 248.7,1617.9 250.5,1622C252.3,1626.1 255.7,1633.9 258,1639.2C261.7,
  1647.7 262.6,1649 264.7,1649C266,1649 302.3,1636.2 345.3,1620.6C484.6,1569.9 536.5,1552.3 598,1534.9C687.3,
  1509.6 751,1499.7 833,1498.3C910.4,1497.1 981.7,1502.4 1175.4,1524.1C1209.9,1527.9 1238.5,1530.8 1238.8,
  1530.5C1239.1,1530.2 1238.9,1529.5 1238.4,1529C1236.9,1527.5 1083.3,1510.5 1012.5,1504.1C977.8,1500.9 952,
  1498.9 918,1496.8C890.4,1495.1 807.3,1495.1 786.5,1496.8C667.8,1506.5 588.8,1528.4 325.5,1624.5C301.9,
  1633.2 278.4,1641.7 273.5,1643.5L264.4,1646.8L262.6,1642.2C261.5,1639.6 259.2,1634.1 257.4,1630C240.3,
  1591.2 226.7,1560.4 224.2,1555C222.6,1551.4 219.3,1544.2 217,1539C214.7,1533.8 211.2,1526.1 209.3,
  1522C207.3,1517.9 205.1,1512.9 204.3,1511C203.5,1509.1 199.1,1499.2 194.5,1489C181.7,1460.5 170,1434 170,
  1433.5C170,1433.3 168.9,1430.6 167.5,1427.7C166.2,1424.7 163.5,1418.5 161.6,1413.9C159.8,1409.3 157.2,
  1403.2 156,1400.5C152.6,1392.8 147.7,1380.8 136.8,1353.5C93.8,1245.6 65.7,1140.1 51.6,1033.5C47.8,
  1004.6 46.4,991.6 43,953L39.9,917.6L40.3,833.5C40.6,767.5 41,745.5 42.3,731C43.2,720.8 44.3,705.7 44.9,
  697.5C49.9,624.9 54.9,579.6 63.5,527.8C73,471.4 87,412.7 98.9,379.7C100,376.9 102.5,369.8 104.5,
  364C114.5,335.8 133.8,294.7 148.5,270.5C179.3,219.7 218.9,178 264.2,148.5C309.6,118.8 353.1,103 413.5,
  94.4C428.2,92.3 483.3,91.3 493.3,92.9C540.2,100.4 562.5,104.9 582,110.6C633.4,125.6 690.7,155.4 735.5,
  190.5C761.6,210.9 778.2,226 803.5,252.1C848.6,298.5 881.2,342.1 949.8,447C955.3,455.5 960.3,462.9 960.7,
  463.5C962.1,465.1 966.4,473 985.5,508.5C991.4,519.5 997,529.8 998,531.5C1010.8,553.4 1055.2,641.6 1069.3,
  673C1070.7,676 1075,685.6 1078.9,694.2C1082.8,702.9 1086,710.2 1086,710.5C1086,710.7 1087.1,713.3 1088.4,
  716.2C1104,750.4 1129.6,818.1 1144.8,865.5C1155.7,899.5 1157.8,906.6 1169.4,948C1182,993.3 1200.4,
  1075.1 1209.9,1129C1211.1,1135.3 1212.9,1145.4 1213.9,1151.5C1215,1157.5 1216.4,1166.8 1216.9,
  1172C1217.5,1177.2 1220.2,1202.4 1223,1228C1225.7,1253.6 1228.6,1280.3 1229.5,1287.5C1230.3,1294.6 1231.9,
  1309 1233,1319.5C1234.1,1329.9 1235.4,1342.5 1236,1347.5C1239.3,1376.6 1240,1395.5 1240,1462.7C1240,
  1522.7 1240.2,1531 1241.5,1531C1242.8,1531 1243,1522.6 1243,1461.2C1243,1388.5 1242.5,1376.3 1238,
  1336C1237,1326.4 1234.5,1303.6 1232.5,1285.5C1230.6,1267.3 1228.3,1246.9 1227.5,1240C1226.7,1233.1 1224.4,
  1212.9 1222.5,1195C1218.5,1158.1 1218.4,1157.4 1212.9,1127.5C1201.1,1062.5 1189.9,1012.7 1171.9,
  945C1168.2,931.2 1162.6,911.8 1156.1,890.5C1122.5,780.1 1071.5,660.7 1007.2,542C961.9,458.2 969.5,
  470.9 924.5,403C903.6,371.5 869.7,323.4 866,320C865.7,319.7 861.4,314.3 856.5,308C851.6,301.7 846.6,
  295.4 845.4,294L833.4,280C771.7,208.3 707.6,159 632.4,125.7C596.3,109.7 567,101.7 511,92.5C489.7,89 489.2,
  89 461,89.2C445.3,89.2 430.9,89.5 429,89.7Z"
  android:strokeWidth="1"
  android:fillColor="#f0000000"
  android:strokeColor="#000000"/>
```

I tried to fill this region in with color. I use `DrawableCompat.setTint(mInsoleRegion1.getDrawable(), Color.parseColor(color[1]));` to set and parse the color that I have given it in my other activity. However the only thing it does is give the borders a color with whatever is defined.

My question now is, how would I need to go about editing the second file so that it fills the entire region with the color I want?

Edit: I have tried out the listed answer below and this still only colors the borders for the second XML, however it does work as intended for the first XML. I fixed this for the second XML by editing the pathdata of the first XML to look like the drawable of the second. After doing this it worked normally again.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code to your first vector XML file, within the `path` section:

```
android:fillColor="@android:color/red"
```

Replace the color with whatever color you want.

Comment: Would this still work hand in hand with `DrawableCompat.setTint(mInsoleRegion1.getDrawable(), Color.parseColor(color[1]));` ?

Comment: @MatthewLeonhart I don't know, you would have to test it out. But I did pull your vector file into a project and confirmed that my addition worked.

Comment: I have tried it out and sadly it doesn't work. Did you perhaps try it out with the first XML file? The first XML file works but the problem is with the second one where I had to convert a jpg to svg

Comment: @MatthewLeonhart Yes, I confirmed it worked with the first XML file. Updated answer to clarify that the solution works with the first file.

Comment: It seems the problem with the second xml file was due to it being edited in jpg format and then converted to svg. I don't really get why it didn't work nor do I know if it should work like that, but after fiddling around with the svg file of the first XML and changing the pathdata I managed to make it work.